# getting last interaction from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables that look somewhat like this:

```
tbl_rating_yes
ID,     rater,   rated,   ratetype, mry_timestamp
1       1234     3456       3       '2015-06-01 23:01:00:000'
2       1234     7666       3       '2013-06-01 23:02:00:000'
3       5678     1234       3       '2013-06-01 23:14:00:000'
4       9085     4567       3       '2013-06-01 23:19:00:000'

tbl_rating_no
ID,     rater,   rated,   ratetype, mrn_timestamp
1       6679     1234       1       '2015-06-01 13:09:00:000'
2       1234     9900       1       '2015-06-01 13:10:00:000'
3       8891     1111       1       '2015-06-01 14:56:00:000'
4       0010     4545       1       '2015-06-01 15:06:00:000'

tbl_rating_maybe
ID,     rater,   rated,   ratetype, mrm_timestamp
1       5632     9000       2       '2013-06-01 11:00:59:000'
2       3421     8787       2       '2013-06-01 12:44:00:000'
3       0100     9887       2       '2013-06-01 16:04:00:000'
4       9085     1234       2       '2013-06-02 01:22:00:000'
```

i'd like to be able to find out the last interaction that rater `9085` did.

currently i have a query like:

```
SELECT GREATEST(IFNULL(`mrm_timestamp`,'1900-01-01 01:01:01'),
                IFNULL(`mrn_timestamp`,'1900-01-01 01:01:01'),
                IFNULL(`mry_timestamp`,'1900-01-01 01:01:01')) as timestamp
FROM tbl_rating_no rn
LEFT JOIN tbl_rating_yes ry
ON ry.`rater` = rn.`rater`
LEFT JOIN tbl_rating_maybe rm
ON rm.`rater` = rn.`rater`
WHERE rn.rater = 9085
ORDER BY timestamp
```

but since `9085` doesn't exist in the no rating table, it doesn't bring back a result.  I'd like to be able to bring back the timestamp, the ratetype and the id at the least.  there shouldn't be clashes but if there are bring back all the results for the max time.  so this should ideally bring back the information from `tbl_rating_maybe`.

Comment: why have 3 tables? why not 1 table with a "rating" field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `union all` and `limit`:

```
select r.*
from ((select r.*
       from tbl_rating_yes r
       where r.rater = 9085
       order by mry_timestamp desc
       limit 1
      )
      union all
      (select r.*
       from tbl_rating_no r
       where r.rater = 9085
       order by mrn_timestamp desc
       limit 1
      )
      union all
      (select r.*
       from tbl_rating_maybe r
       where r.rater = 9085
       order by mrm_timestamp desc
       limit 1
      )
     ) r
order by mry_timestamp desc
limit 1;
```

In fact, having multiple tables with essentially the same structure is typically a bad idea.  You should consider restructuring your tables by combining these three into a single table, with a column containing the rating.

Comment: we had that, but our database couldn't take it. i'm not a DBA in the slightest so i'll have to presume the people that are vaguely know what they're doing.